# Rails 3.1 Devise all of a sudden redirecting to wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, routes

My login was working fine but I don't know where I messed things up. When I login it redirects me sessions/user which is wrong. Here is the error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/sessions/user"
```

Here is my routes.rb:

```
 Wal::Application.routes.draw do

 resources :sessions,   :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]



 devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions]

devise_for :users  do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end 

resources :posts do
resources :comments
end
resources :users, :only => [:show]
resources :microsposts, :only => [:create, :destroy]
match '/' => "home#index", :as => :home

match 'home/index', :to => 'home#index'

get "users/show"

root :to => "home#index"
#get "home/index"

 resources :users do
    member do
     get :following, :followers
   end
end

resources :microsposts, :only => [:create, :destroy]
resources :relationships, :only => [:create, :destroy]
```

application controller:

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   protect_from_forgery

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    current_user # <- Path you want to redirect the user to after signup
    end
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   current_user
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    stored_location_for(resource) || welcome_path
  end
end
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-out

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will solve your problem, but the first line:

> Wal::Application.routes.draw do

has no corresponding 'end' in the code that you posted.

Comment: I double checked, I do, I just didn't copy it. It was way at the bottom below the comments